# Is it possible to send embeds with reddit-fetch?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Is it possible to send embeds with reddit-fetch?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const redditFetch = require("reddit-fetch");

module.exports = {
    name: "subreddit",
    async run (client, message, args) {
        if (message.channel.id === "706224671384666123"){

            const Embedis = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Meme')
            .setColor('#FF4081')
            .setDescription(`${message.author}, heres a meme for ya`)
            .setImage(`${post.url}`)

        redditFetch({
            subreddit: 'meme',
            sort: 'random',
            allowNSFW: false,
            allowModPost: true,
            allowCrossPost: true,
        }).then(post => {
            message.channel.send(Embedis);
        });
    }
}};
```

The `post` is undefined in this situation, I gave it a couple of tries, maybe somebody could have an idea for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `post` before it's defined. You have to create the embed in the callback.

```js
redditFetch({
 subreddit: 'meme',
 sort: 'random',
 allowNSFW: false,
 allowModPost: true,
 allowCrossPost: true,
}).then((post) => {
 const Embedis = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Meme')
  .setColor('#FF4081')
  .setDescription(`${message.author}, heres a meme for ya`)
  .setImage(post.url);
 message.channel.send(Embedis);
});
```